# ng-submit is not working in AngularJs while controller is properly working

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJs. I am creating a website and there are several forms on the website. The same code with ng-submit is working on other pages. But not here.
The controller, ng-options and validations are working properly.

I tried changing function and checking the function

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PostspaceFormController as LoginFormCtrl">
    <div class="divider-30 d-none d-lg-block"></div>
    <form class="form-styling" name="LoginForm" ng-submit="submitDataInForm3()" novalidate>
        <fieldset ng-disabled="sendingMail">
            <p class="fs-l-17 fw-l-500 margin-styling">Post Your Space Requirement</p>
            <div class="form-group m-0" ng-class="{'has-error': LoginForm.email.$invalid && LoginForm.email.$touched}">
                <label class="form-label label-styling">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-styling" ng-model="data.email" name="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                <div class="error-state ">
                    <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.email.$error.required && LoginForm.email.$touched">Email is Required</span>
                    <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.email.$touched && LoginForm.email.$invalid && !LoginForm.email.$error.required">Invalid Email Address</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-0" ng-class="{'has-error': LoginForm.mobile.$invalid && LoginForm.mobile.$touched}">
                <label class="form-label label-styling">Your Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-styling" ng-model="data.mobile" name="mobile" required pattern="^\d{4,12}$">
                <div class="error-state ">
                    <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.mobile.$error.required && LoginForm.mobile.$touched">Mobile Number is Required</span>
                    <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.mobile.$touched && LoginForm.mobile.$invalid && !LoginForm.mobile.$error.required">Invalid Mobile Number</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-0" ng-class="{'has-error': LoginForm.name.$invalid && LoginForm.name.$touched}">
                <label class="form-label label-styling">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-styling" ng-model="data.name" name="name" placeholder="" required>
                <div class="error-state ">
                    <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.name.$error.required && LoginForm.name.$touched">Name is Required</span>
                    <!-- <span class="error-label text-danger margin-styling" ng-show="LoginForm.name.$touched && LoginForm.name.$invalid && !LoginForm.name.$error.required">Invalid Name</span> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group m-0">
                <label class="form-label label-styling">What are you looking for?</label>
                <select class="form-control input-styling" required name="spacetype" ng-change="changeSelected(workingSpace)" ng-model="workingSpace" ng-options="type as type.category for type in spaceTypes" ng-class="{'not-selected': !workingSpace}">
                    <option value="" disabled="">Select Type Of Space</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn-color fs-l-14 h5 btn-block btn-lg text-center rounded-0 margin-styling border-0" ng-disabled="sendingMail" ng-class="{'running': sendingMail}">
                    <span ng-hide="sendingMail">BOOK YOUR SPACE NOW</span>
                    <span ng-show="sendingMail">Submitting</span>
                    <div ng-show="sendingMail" class="ld ld-ring ld-spin"></div>
                </button>
            </div>    
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `not working`? Can you post submit function's code?

Comment: The `submit` event will be blocked if an HTML5 input fails validation.